# Is it possible to declare a pointer to a function with unknown (at compile time) return type

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers

I have a `class A` in which I want to have a pointer to a function as data member:

```
class A
{
  protected:
    double (*ptrToFunction) ( double );

  public:
  ...
  //Setting function according to its name
  void SetPtrToFunction( std::string fName );
};
```

But what if I want `ptrToFunction` to be sometimes `double` and sometimes - `int`, to have something like:

```
//T is a typename
T(*ptrToFunction) ( double );
```

How should I declare it in this case?

Comment: How do you want to use this function?

Comment: More importantly, how does the caller know what it's expecting back?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A [discriminated union](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/discriminated-unions/240009296) can do that for you:

```
class A
{
  template<T>
  using cb_type = T(double);

  protected:
     enum {IS_INT, IS_DOUBLE} cb_tag;
     union {
       cb_type<int>    *ptrToIntFunction;
       cb_type<double> *ptrToDoubleFunction;
     };

  public:
  ...
  // Setting function according to its name
  void SetPtrToFunction( std::string fName );
};
```

A more general and elegant solution for a discriminated union can be applied with `std::variant` in C++17, or `boost::variant` for earlier standard revisions.

---

Alternatively, if you want to completely ignore the return type, you can convert the member into [`std::function<void(double)>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and benefit from type erasure. The `Callable` concept will see the call via pointer converted into `static_cast<void>(INVOKE(...))` and discard the return value, whatever it is.

To [illustrate](https://ideone.com/CvyA1R):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int foo(double d)  { std::cout << d << '\n'; return 0; }

char bar(double d) { std::cout << 2*d << '\n'; return '0'; }

int main() {
    std::function<void(double)> cb;

    cb = foo; cb(1.0);

    cb = bar; cb(2.0);

    return 0;
}
```

---

And finally, if you *do care* about the return value but don't want to *store* a discriminated union. Then knowing about unions and the behavior of `std::function`, you can combine the above two approaches.

[Like this](https://ideone.com/gxAA98)

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int    foo(double d) { return d; }

double bar(double d) { return 2*d; }

struct Result {
    union {
        int    i_res;
        double d_res;
    };
    enum { IS_INT, IS_DOUBLE } u_tag;

    Result(Result const&) = default;
    Result(int i)  : i_res{i}, u_tag{IS_INT} {}
    Result(double d) : d_res{d}, u_tag{IS_DOUBLE} {}

    Result& operator=(Result const&) = default;
    auto& operator=(int i)
    { i_res = i; u_tag = IS_INT;    return *this; }
    auto& operator=(double d)
    { d_res = d; u_tag = IS_DOUBLE; return *this; }
};

int main() {
    std::function<Result(double)> cb;

    cb = foo;
    auto r = cb(1.0);
    assert(r.u_tag == Result::IS_INT);
    std::cout << r.i_res << '\n';

    cb = bar;
    r = cb(2.0);
    assert(r.u_tag == Result::IS_DOUBLE); 
    std::cout << r.d_res << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't mind but this is a bit complex to understand. Few inline comments would help. What is the use of `cb_tag`?

Comment: @SauravSahu - It's the tag part of the tagged union idiom.  You set this member along with the member of the union, so you can later know which union member is safe to access.

Comment: Good point to use an `std::function` to erase the return type. +1

Comment: @SauravSahu - Linked to an article about discriminated unions.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what the `cb_tag` and the union are connected with in your first solution with using discriminated  unions. I have read the article you linked to and still do not realize what if I set `cb_tag` with `IS_DOUBLE` and tried to return `double` when active member of the union is `int`. What it would be? I do not see any connection between them.

Comment: @paraxod - The tag is for you to know what the union holds. It's your job to do the bookkeeping. There's no magic that makes the tag match the active member. If you don't, your program will have undefined behavior.

Comment: OK. I thought so. Just wanted to sure. Trying to understand the rest of your answer.

Comment: @paraxod - I think the last solution is probably the most involved. But it also fleshes out much of the bookkeeping of a tagged union. The rest is done by the brilliant specification of `std::function`,

Answer (score 1):

If your class doesn't have a template, as in your example, you could do this:

```
template <class T>
struct myStruct
{
  static T (*ptrToFunction)(double);
};
```

Comment: Why static? Worth noting that this contrains each instance to returning only one return type (if static removed). Of course, this may be what is wanted.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you are using `dlsym` / `GetProcAddress` to get the functions address.

In this case, you need at least 2 call sites to disambiguate the call, as the CPU actually does different things for each of these calls.

```
enum ReturnType { rtInt, rtDouble };
void SetPtrToFunction( std::string fName , enum ReturnType typeOfReturn );

struct Function {
   enum ReturnType rt;
   union {
          std::function< int(double) > mIntFunction;
          std::function< double(double) > mDoubleFunction;
   } u;
} mFunction;
```

So the function would need to be instantiated with a known return type, and then this used with some tagged union to get the correct function call.

```
  int A::doCall( double value ) {
      if( mFunction.rt == rtInt ) {
          int result = mFunction.mIntFunction( value );
      } else if( mFunction.rt == rtDouble ) {
          double result = mFunction.mDoubleFunction( value );
      }
  }
```

Comment: You mean [`dlsym`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) (not `dlfun`) and you probably mean raw function pointers, not `std::function`-s

Comment: I see nothing in the question that implies a dynamic library call.

Comment: @SteveKidd I was not familiar with another mechanism which associated a string with a function than using GetProcAddress/dlsym

Comment: @kmsteve Sorry - I see your point. An alternative is a hardcoded if/else that sets the function pointer according to value of input string.